# Split String into dictionary words and non-dictionary words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

I want to split a string into a sequence of words using a dictionary.

The following function only gives me words with letter boundaries.

```
function spltToWord(prm){
    var spltedAr = prm.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/);
    return spltedAr.join(" ").trim();
}
```

I want to separate the text into dictionary/non-dictionary words.

For example:

**Iamno123prisoner** - I am no 123 prisoner

**USAisveryrich** - USA is very rich

**Albertgaveme5rupees** - Albert gave me 5 rupees

> A sample dictionary can be found [Here](http://app4pc.com/static/images/words.txt) for refrence.

Comment: I think you should look into dynamic programming approach here.

May be this will help you somehow.
 http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dictionary contains many words, you'll want a faster solution than matching one word at a time against substrings of the input text. If there are ten thousand words in the dictionary, you have to do at least ten thousand character comparisons with this naive approach.

A more efficient solution involves the use of a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in which you've stored the dictionary words. Checking whether a word is in the dictionary requires only a single pass through the string.

Another advantage is that you can search for the longest match starting from a given position in the text. This approach is demonstrated in the following snippet, which includes a small dictionary that suffices to process your examples. You can replace this with your own dictionary when you run the code locally.

```js
var Global = {
  dictionary: [
    'aa', 'I', 'i', 's',
    'aah', 'am',
    'aahed', 'no',
    'aahing', '123',
    'aahs', 'prisoner',
    'aal', 'USA',
    'aalii', 'is',
    'aaliis', 'very',
    'aals', 'rich',
    'aardvark', 'Albert',
    'aardvarks', 'gave', 'me', '5', 'rupees'
  ]
};

function addToTrie(word) {
  var node = Global.trie;
  for (var pos = 0; pos < word.length; ++pos) {
    var letter = word.charAt(pos);
    if (node[letter] === undefined) {
      node[letter] = {};
    }
    node = node[letter];
  }
  node.terminal = true;
}

function findLongestMatch(text, start) {
  var node = Global.trie,
      best = start - 1;
  for (var pos = start; pos < text.length; ++pos) {
    var letter = text.charAt(pos);
    if (node[letter] === undefined) {
      break;
    }
    node = node[letter];
    if (node.terminal) {
      best = pos;
    }
  }
  return best - start + 1;
}

function loadTrie() {
  var words = Global.dictionary,
      trie = Global.trie = {};
  words.forEach(function (word) {
    addToTrie(word);
  });
};

function println(label, s, labelStyle) {
  if (s === undefined) {
    s = label || '';
  } else {
    var className = 'label' + (labelStyle ? ' ' + labelStyle : '');
    s = '<div class="' + className + '">' + label + '</div> ' + s;
  }
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += (s + '<br />');
}

function process(text) {
  var results = [],
      letters = [],
      pos = 0;
  while (pos < text.length) {
    var length = findLongestMatch(text, pos);
    if (length == 0) {
      letters.push(text.charAt(pos));
      pos += 1;
    } else {
      if (letters.length != 0) {
        results.push({ word: letters.join(''), known: false });
        letters = [];
      }
      results.push({ word: text.substring(pos, pos + length), known: true });
      pos += length;
    }
  }
  if (letters.length != 0) {
    results.push({ word: letters.join(''), known: false });
    letters = [];
  }
  var breakdown = results.map(function (result) {
    return result.word;
  });
  println();
  println('    breakdown:',  '/' + breakdown.join('/') + '/');
  results.forEach(function (result) {
    println((result.known ? 'in dictionary' : '      unknown') + ':',
        '"' + result.word + '"', (result.known ? undefined : 'unknown'));
  });
};

window.onload = function () {
  loadTrie();
  process('WellIamno123prisoner');
  process('TheUSAisveryrichman');
  process('Albertgaveme5rupeesyo');
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #aaa;
  text-align: right;
}
.label.unknown {
  color: #c61c39;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit #2**

```
var words = ["apple", "banana", "candy", "cookie", "doughnut"];
var input = "banana123candynotawordcookieblahdoughnut";
var currentWord = "",
    result = "";

while (true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        currentWord += input[i];
        if (words.indexOf(currentWord) >= 0) {
            result += " " + currentWord + " ";
            currentWord = "";
        }
    }

    if (currentWord.length > 0) {
        result += currentWord[0];
        input = currentWord.substr(1);
        currentWord = "";
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

console.log(result.trim()); // "banana 123 candy notaword cookie blah doughnut"
```

Note the result will contain two spaces if there are two consecutive dictionary words. You can fix this using regex.

It isn't the prettiest solution (you can make it recursive which may be more readable), and it doesn't provide multiple solutions (see DP link in comment for that).

<strike>**Edit** this doesn't take into account non-dictionary words.</strike>

Using a simple greedy algorithm:

```
var words = ["apple", "banana", "candy", "cookie", "doughnut"];
var input = "bananacandycookiedoughnut";
var currentWord = "", result = "";

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    currentWord += input[i];
    if (words.indexOf(currentWord) >= 0) {
        result += currentWord + " ";
        currentWord = "";
    }
}

console.log(result.trim()); // "banana candy cookie donught"
```

Of course you would want to modify various part of this, e.g. use a set for the dictionary and take into account case [in]sensitivity.

Comment: It is working good but when i'm having words "i" and "is" (means same starting) var words = ["prisoner", "i", "am", "no", "very", "is", "rich","gave","me","rupees"]. It gives "USA i s very  rich" for "USAisveryrich"

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Yes, that is the downside of a greedy approach. The algorithm looks for the first occurrence of any word in the dictionary. It does not search for all solutions, and thus does not look for an optimal solution (e.g. one where word lengths are maximized). If you wanted to look at all solutions, you should go with a DP approach (see the link in the comments)

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Again, that would require a slightly different approach, which is well outlined in the linked article (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/)

Comment: I agree with your point. I want something in Javascript, I'm not aware of c language. So both one is not complete answer for future user who will visit this question and by the way I'm very thankful for all your effort.